# Azure DevOps CI/CD not deploying my pipeline triggers in an Active state

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-data-factory, continuous-deployment

My dev ADF has pipeline triggers that are Active and set to run every hour. Using devops repos & CI/CD, I deployed these triggers from our dev to test ADF environments. The pipeline triggers were successfully created in my test environment, but they are inactive. Why are these not coming over in a 'Started' status. The ARM template shows the trigger as Started

These need to be turned on automatically after deployment as I don't have rights to turn these on manually.  I can't tell if this is a bug or if I'm missing something to turn these on within the deployment.  Please see screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have the same issue and are using a powershell step in Azure Devops to enable the trigger:

```bsh
Start-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Trigger -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryResourceName -Name $PipelineTriggerName -Force
```