# POwershell CI/CD Error Disconnect-AzAccount -Scope Process -ErrorAction Stop , Clear-AzContext -Scope Process -ErrorAction Stop

Tags: powershell, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

I was Working on the CI/CD pipeline in Azure data factory and need to create a release in the DataFactory, I was able to create a release successfully But I have triggers running on the Data Factory I have to use Powershell Deployment Template, The Deployment was Successfully done but the triggers were not stopped I have got an error
Clear-AzContext -Scope Process -ErrorAction Stop
Disconnect-AzAccount -Scope Process -ErrorAction Stop
I am not good at PowerShell so If any body can help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure DevOps CI/CD not deploying my pipeline triggers in an Active state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62327263/azure-devops-ci-cd-not-deploying-my-pipeline-triggers-in-an-active-state)

Comment: Hi Cece Dong Actually The problem is I worked according to Microsoft DOcs 
Use Azure Power Shell given required parameters and script and Resource name 
I also get logs while Release but triggers doesn't stop in data Factory

Comment: 2020-11-03T10:35:19.8462045Z Getting triggers
2020-11-03T10:35:21.9921456Z Stopping deployed triggers
2020-11-03T10:35:21.9980593Z Unsubscribing DailySync_Trigger from events
2020-11-03T10:35:39.2073804Z Stopping trigger DailySync_Trigger
2020-11-03T10:35:40.8810807Z True
2020-11-03T10:36:18.9416393Z ##[command]Disconnect-AzAccount -Scope Process -ErrorAction Stop
2020-11-03T10:36:19.1860937Z ##[command]Clear-AzContext -Scope Process -ErrorAction Stop
2020-11-03T10:36:19.5016376Z ## Script Execution Complete
2020-11-03T10:36:19.5540764Z ##[section]Finishing: Stop Triggers

Answer (score 0):

As Azure Data Factory relies on ARM for deployments, a PowerShell scripted is required to handle trigger starting and stopping, resource deletion and deployment clean up.

It is recommended by the product team to copy the script in our documentation as is and run it as a PowerShell script before and after the ARM deployment. The script and associated parameters are located at https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-deployment#script